# Where do I place the configuration for Act-as-taggable-on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm reading the act-as-taggable Github document, 
https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on,  and I want to force tags to be saved downcase. The instruction in the Configuration section says to add the line

`ActsAsTaggableOn.force_lowercase = true`

but I'm not quite sure where this would go.

In what file am I supposed to put this piece of code?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you can create a file called acts_as_taggable_on_configuration.rb on initializers directory, and place all configuration in it. Remember to restart your application after create this file.

Comment: I had this error when my gem was too old... for example 2.2.2 gives the error, while 2.3.3 is good!

Answer (score 13):

You can create a custom initializer in `config/initializers` and put this line there.

Or alternatively, you can set this in `config/application.rb`:

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ActsAsTaggableOn.force_lowercase = true
  end
end
```

Comment: If you do a custom initializer, what do you declare the class, inheritance or wrapper as?